# Related Products ACF WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am not using a WooCommerce plugin, just your normal site.

I have a page, which I need to let the user select some 'related products'.

Now, I am using ACF, and looking at using the Post_Object to allow the user to select the product.

What this needs to do, is get the product name, but also get that products image and description.

I have used this code, from the ACF site, to attempt to grab the post object title.

```
    <?php

$post_object = get_field('post_object');

if( $post_object ): 

    // override $post
    $post = $post_object;
    setup_postdata( $post ); 

    ?>
    <div>
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <span>Post Object Custom Field: <?php the_field('field_name'); ?></span>
    </div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But even this won't display anything?

Is there any obvious issues anyone can see?

Comment: Do you allow multiple selections? That can change how the code works, and I'd need to know that before I can answer.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: In your field settings for your 'related products' Post Object field, there is an option called "Select multiple values?". Do you have that set to Yes or No. If it is set to Yes, and you want to be able to select multiple Related Products, that will change the code that you would want to use.

Comment: Apologies, Yes I will be having more than 1 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are allowing multiple selections, the get_field will return an array of post objects. So you will need to loop through that array, using the following code. This code assumes that your Post Object field is named 'related_products', and then calls the post's excerpt value, which will check the Excerpt Field first, and if not present, will generate an excerpt from The Content of the post.

```
    $related_products = get_field('related_products');

    if( $related_products ): ?>
            <ul>
            <?php foreach( $related_products as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
                    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                    <li>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
    <?php endif;
```

Comment: THis has now allowed me to dd a product, which is great.

The Description is different though. Im using the custom post type excerpt for the description, or even just the actual description would be great.

I need to basically get the product, and from this, get the description from the product

Comment: Great. If this solution solved your problem, be sure accept the answer in order to help others with similar problems.

Comment: Sorry, Pressed enter by mistake!

Comment: I'm not too familiar with woocommerce. Is the description of the product a separate custom field, or is it just the post's content field?

Comment: Im not using WooCommerce, Its just a custom post type

Comment: So you want to just grab an excerpt from the post's main content editor?

Comment: Yeah, It's a custom post type if thats any different.

Comment: Nope, no difference at all, so you would want to call the_excerpt(). I just edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your work/time!

Your a saver!